# Changing value of point according to points' value inside its buffer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, fields-attributes, buffer, polygon-creation

In QGIS I have a layer with points and every point has a value. I would like to create one buffer with a specific radius for each point.

In addition, I would like every point to acquire a new value the average of the points' values for the points which are inside the buffer. If the point's buffer doesn't include any other point, the point's value will not change.

My professor told me about *Spatial Moving Average* and *Floating Catchment Area* but I have no idea how to use them.